# How can I detect the screen resolution of a Windows Phone device?

Tags: c#, monogame, windows-phone-8

I want to detect if a device uses WVGA, WXGA, 720p or 1080p resolution. In addition, I want to store the resolution of the device in a variable. For example, if the resolution is 800x480 pixel, then the variable has the value: string CurrentResolution = "720p".

How can I do that? How can I detect the screen resolution of a Windows Phone device?

Comment: Pretty sure you can just use 'GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth' and  'GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight'.

Comment: It's not working with the 1080p emulator. It detects 1279x720 pixel if I choose the 1080p emulator. But I need to know if the emulator/device has a 720p or a 1080p resolution. How can I detect 1080p resolution?